# Was ist ein Kompetenznetzwerk?

Tags: meaning

Das Wort ist in Nachrichten oder Organisationsnamen oft anzutreffen.

Aber was bezeichnet es?

Comment: The word *expert* had been sucked dry so they had to create a new euphemism for *muppets networking each other simulating competence*.

Comment: Like, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_network?

Comment: Yes. They don't like to call it *Expertennetzwerk* any more in German because of too many "so-called experts", Shredded Cheese Authorities. People hear "inhabitant of an ivory tower" if you say "expert". And that's the best you could get. *Du Experte* is an euphemism for "You half-competent buffoon" since at least the 1970ies. Sometimes varied as *Keksperte!* – Cookie-expert!

Comment: @Janka: Dir ist aber schon aufgefallen, dass die Frage in perfektem Deutsch gestellt wurde? Warum kommentierst du sie auf Englisch?

Comment: Weil der Verfasser sich John Doe genannt hat und seine erste Frage auf Englisch gestellt hat.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Wenn das perfektes Deutsch gewesen ist, dann gehörst Du sicher auch in dieses Kompetenznetzwerk GL :) .

Answer (score 3):

Die Definition eines Kompetenznetzwerks hängt stark von der Branche und dem Kontext ab.

Kompetenznetzwerke finden sich in der Medizin, der Forschung, der Industrie, dem Handel und im Handwerk. Jede Branche versucht das Expertenwissen in einem solchen Netzwerk zu bündeln, wie es auch ein Element des modernen [Wissensmanagements](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wissensmanagement) ist. Was man aber jeweils als Kompetenz versteht und welches Netz aufgebaut werden soll, ist je nach Branche verschieden, daher schwanken die Definitionen stark oder sind sehr schwammig gehalten.

Dies kommt in einer Zeitungsmeldung aus dem Jahr 2000, also in der Zeit in der Kompetenznetze in Mode kamen, gut zum Ausdruck:

> Wir bemühen uns um Lernpartnerschaften für junge Funktionsträger, sei es mit Stiftungen, Unternehmen, Verbänden. **Das Leitbild einer modernen sozialdemokratischen Organisationskultur lässt sich mit dem Begriff "Kompetenznetzwerk" beschreiben.** Zu lange konnte man bei uns Kompetenz durch guten Willen ersetzen. Wer Jugendliche erreichen will, muss aber tatsächlich kompetent sein - zum Beispiel im Umgang mit jungen Medien. <sup>[Die Zeit 41/2000](https://www.zeit.de/2000/41/SPD-Jugendinitiative_Fuers_Leben_lernen)</sup>

Eine unpräzisere Definition des Begriffs lässt sich wohl nur schwer finden.

In der Medizin ist der Begriff sehr häufig zu finden, nachdem Ende der 90er Jahre vom Bundesforschungsministerium ein Programm zur Einrichtung von [Kompetenznetzwerken](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kompetenznetze_in_der_Medizin) eingerichtet wurde. Diese Netze sind bis heute erhalten geblieben und definieren sich in etwa wie folgt:

> In den Kompetenznetzen der Medizin sollen das Wissen und die Erfahrung jener Gruppierungen gebündelt werden, die sich auf verschiedenen Ebenen mit einem speziellen Krankheitsbild beschäftigen. Dies können führende Forschungseinrichtungen und Kliniken, niedergelassene Ärzte, aber auch Patientenorganisationen, Kostenträger oder die Industrie sein. Das Zusammenführen dieses Expertenwissens mit dem Ziel, Ergebnisse aus der Forschung schneller in die Versorgung einfließen zu lassen, ist die vorrangige Aufgabe von Kompetenznetzen. <sup>[Deutsches Ärzteblatt 99, 2002](https://www.aerzteblatt.de/archiv/30461/Kompetenznetze-in-der-Medizin-Eine-Standortbestimmung)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ein Netzwerk ist in diesem Fall eine Gruppe von Personen, die miteinander durch soziale Kontakte verbunden sind. Das heißt, diese Personen kennen einander und sind in manchem Fällen sogar miteinander befreundet. Jedenfalls gibt es in einem Netzwerk immer eine gemeinsame Eigenschaft, die alle Mitglieder dieser Gruppe haben oder ein gemeinsames Interesse.

Das Wort *Kompetenz* ist ein Synonym für *Fähigkeit*, wobei mit *Kompetenz* aber gemeint ist, dass eine Person eine Fähigkeit in einem besonders stark ausgeprägten Maße hat.

Ein *Kompetenznetzwerk* ist daher eine Gruppe von Menschen, die entweder alle dieselbe stark ausgeprägte Fähigkeit haben, oder (und das ist meist eher gemeint) die Menschen haben unterschiedliche Fähigkeiten, die sich gegenseitig gut ergänzen.

In der Praxis schließen sich oftmals mehrere Kleinunternehmer zu so einem Kompetenznetzwerk zusammen. Das Ziel ist, Kunden an befreundete Unternehmen weiterzuleiten, wenn sie Wünsche haben, auf die das eigene Unternehmen nicht spezialisiert ist. Dazu müssen die Mitglieder des Netzwerks die Kompetenzen der anderen Mitglieder gut kennen.

Die Kunden haben den Vorteil, dass Sie wissen, dass ihr Wunsch von jemandem erfüllt wird, der diese spezielle Aufgabe wirklich gut erledigen kann. Die Unternehmer haben den Vorteil, dass sie sich auf ein bestimmte Nische spezialisieren können, und auch dann Aufträge bekommen, wenn sich die Kunden an ein anderes Mitglied des Netzwerkes wenden, das diese Aufgabe nicht so gut bewältigen kann.

Comment: Quelle? Oder ist das deine eigene Interpretation? Ich lese *Kompetenznetzwerk* häufig im Kontext von Forschungseinrichtungen, besonders im Gesundheitswesen auch von Kliniken. Also nicht wirklich "mittelständische Kleinunternehmer".

Comment: Ist es dann ähnlich wie ein Kartell?

Comment: @Takkat: http://www.kompetenz-netzwerk.at https://www.meinbezirk.at/voecklabruck/wirtschaft/kompetenz-netzwerk-gegruendet-d1645683.html https://www.greencare-oe.at/bundesweites-kompetenznetzwerk+2500+1000206

Comment: @J.Doe: Kartelle sind eher Zusammenschlüsse großer Unternehmen mit mehreren hundert oder tausend Mitarbeitern. Die hier beschriebenen Kompetenznetzwerke sind eher Vereinigungen von Kleinbetrieben mit 10 oder weniger Mitarbeitern, und meist nur auf lokaler Ebene.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Danke. Das ist die Definition eines speziellen Netzwerks, nämlich "green care". Gibt es in Österreich noch andere?

Comment: @Takkat Du hast nur auf den letzten Link geklickt.

Comment: Noch ein zweites, nämlich das Kompetenz-Netzwerk "Vöcklabruck-Ried" macht eine Definition des Begriffs nicht wirklich einfacher. Mein Eindruck ist, dass jeder so seine eigene Vorstellung hat, was das sein soll. Klingt auf jeden Fall kompetent ;)

Comment: @Takkat: »Mein Eindruck ist, dass jeder so seine eigene Vorstellung hat, was das sein soll.« Das sehe ich auch so.